# How to run Jetty with Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jersey, jetty

I have a Gradle project, and I'm trying to run it with it Jetty. 
My `build.gradle` file looks like following.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.httpPort = 8080
[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.contextPath = ''
[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.daemon = true
[jettyRun, jettyRunWar, jettyStop]*.stopPort = 8081
[jettyRun, jettyRunWar, jettyStop]*.stopKey = 'stop'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.14'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.14'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.7.v20170914'
    testCompile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.7.v20170914'
}
```

I'm trying to run this project from the command line, and the commands I'm using are:

1. `./gradlew` which should build the project, and outputs the following:

   The Jetty plugin has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Consider using the Gretty (https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty) plugin instead.
           at build_6xw4u3prr68h02k136x2vqowd.run(/myproject/build.gradle:3)
   :help

   Welcome to Gradle 3.2.1.
2. `gradle jettyRun` which failed with the statement **Plugin with id 'jetty' not found.**

So the question is, how do I run such a project? Note that I didn't write this project, I just need to run it on my local machine.

Comment: Jetty 9.4.7 is vulnerable, consider upgrading. - see https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00123.html

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert in Gradle, just a beginner, but i think I found something that can help you.
I was also reading about using jetty with gradle, since I used it frequently with Maven.

Turns out, Jetty as a plugin is no longer supported as you can find here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html

Instead, you are supposed to use gretty for the same end:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: worst plugin I've ever had the displeasure to use.. I appreciate your answer tho.