# How to add Jetty to the Netbeans list of avilable web servers?

Tags: java, netbeans, webserver, jetty, war

as:

[image: no jetty]

where and how do I add `jetty` itself?

Looking to deploy the `war` file to `/var/lib/jetty9/webapps/`.

There's no "jetty" available in the plugins that I see.

Comment: I don't think there is a Jetty plugin for NetBeans 12.4, so that won't work. But there are a couple of inferior approaches that you can consider: [1] With a Maven project, you can run Jetty as an embedded server. See [Creating and Configuring Jetty 9 Server in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/jetty-java-programmatic) and [Embedded Jetty Server in Java with Maven](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jetty/article.html#embeddingjetty) for configuration & sample code. I don't know about Gradle though. [2] Run Jetty as a standalone server, and deploy manually. Less convenient, but it will surely work.

Comment: running jetty as a standalone server is fine. I don't understand what's meant by maven with Jetty, because jetty is a server.  Not seeing how maven solves that, although I suppose you can add Jetty dependencies using maven, but don't see how that gives you a server.  I'll have to read more about how that might be useful.

Comment: OK. This very brief summary will get you started: [Using Jetty as standalone server](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jetty/article.html#using-jetty-as-standalone-server). There's also a plugin for Gradle named **gretty** but I don't know anything about it beyond this SO question/answer: [How to run Jetty with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51979257/2985643).

Comment: no worries @skomisa and your comments are more than sufficient.  I was hopeful of having simply overlooking the "jetty" button or similar.  You've given me enough to dig into.  thx.

Comment: Or you can just make a junit testcase with Jetty for your application and have it started and evaluated that way.  (way faster to do, way faster to start, and is also compatible with all IDEs)